# SQL to return another table's value when CASE statement is true

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a SQL statement that returns a value based on a CASE statement that has three possible outcomes.

1) If the column value begins with 'C0' then it returns a concatenation of two columns in the table

2) If the column begins with 'L0' then take the value in another column (_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER) in that row and see if that value resides in another table.  If not, return the value _PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER.

3)If _PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER does reside in the other table, then return the value in the column "Rollup_Project" in the other table, "Rollup_Project_Mapping".

The statement I've written below works fine except for line 12, `"Rollup_Project_Mapping"."Rollup_Project"` where I want it to return the other table's value if the _PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER is found in the other table.  Here is the error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 12:      FROM "Rollup_Project_Mapping"."Rollup_Project"
```

Does anyone know how I can return the value in the other table when this part of the CASE statement is true?

```
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN LEFT("_PROJECT_NUMBER",2)='C0' THEN
    '('||"_PROJECT_NUMBER"||') '||"_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION"
  WHEN LEFT("_PROJECT_NUMBER",2)='L0' THEN
    CASE
      WHEN (SELECT "Rollup_Project" FROM "Project_Rollup_Mapping" WHERE "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST"."_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER" = "Project_Rollup_Mapping"."Project") IS NOT NULL THEN
        "Rollup_Project_Mapping"."Rollup_Project"
    ELSE "_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER"
    END
END AS Rollup_Project2
FROM "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use just a set of `WHEN`/`THEN` statements and `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LEFT("_PROJECT_NUMBER",2) = 'C0'
             THEN '('||"_PROJECT_NUMBER"||') '||"_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION"
             WHEN LEFT("_PROJECT_NUMBER",2) = 'L0' AND
                  EXISTS (SELECT "Rollup_Project" FROM "Project_Rollup_Mapping" WHERE "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST"."_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER" = "Project_Rollup_Mapping"."Project")
                  THEN (SELECT "Rollup_Project" FROM "Project_Rollup_Mapping" WHERE "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST"."_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER" = "Project_Rollup_Mapping"."Project")
             ELSE "_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER"
       END) AS Rollup_Project2
FROM "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST";
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the original SQL statement to work based on @Gordon Linoff answer in case anyone wanted it as another option:

```
SELECT
CASE 
  WHEN LEFT("_PROJECT_NUMBER",2)='C0' THEN
    '('||"_PROJECT_NUMBER"||') '||"_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION"
  WHEN LEFT("_PROJECT_NUMBER",2)='L0' AND (SELECT "Rollup_Project" FROM "Project_Rollup_Mapping" WHERE "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST"."_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER" = "Project_Rollup_Mapping"."Project") IS NOT NULL THEN
    (SELECT "Rollup_Project" FROM "Project_Rollup_Mapping" WHERE "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST"."_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER" = "Project_Rollup_Mapping"."Project")
  ELSE "_PARENT_PROJECT_NUMBER"
END AS Rollup_Project2
FROM "PA_ACCOUNTED_TEST";
```