# Conditionally select different relation to reflect overriding by user (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am looking to override the content in a table during a SELECT with the values from a different table (with the same fields) in case those exit. I am using Postgres.

My use case is: I derive and store some data (mostly relations between other tables), but want users to be able to correct those. On a query, those user-corrected data and relations should be returned, but I do not want to loose the originals.

How can I do this?

- I guess I could [conditionally select from other tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109716/sql-to-return-another-tables-value-when-case-statement-is-true), but is that the best way?
- Do I  have to implement the conditionality for every field manually, or can I do that all in one go?

I could also do this in application logic, but would prefer a clean solution in the DB if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a left join with case statements:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN different_table.id IS NULL THEN content_table.name 
      ELSE different_table.name END AS name,
    CASE 
      WHEN different_table.id IS NULL THEN content_table.price 
      ELSE different_table.price END AS price
FROM content_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN different_table ON content_table.id = different_table.id
```